# Solution for delaying events for N days

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, azure-storage-queues

We're currently writing an application in Microsoft Azure and we're planning to use Event Hubs to handle processing of real time events.

However, after an initial processing we will have to delay further processing of the events for N number of days. The process will work like this:

Event triggered -> Place event in Event Hub -> Event gets fetched from Event Hub and processed -> Event should be delay for X days -> Event gets' further processed (two last steps might be a loop)

How can we achieve this delay of further event processing without using polling or similar strategies. One idea is to use Azure Queues and their visibility timeout, but 7 days is the supported maximum according to the documentation and our business demands are in the 1-3 months maximum range. Number of events in our system should be max 10k per day.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you mind me asking why you do not want to use polling? Otherwise you could store the (serialized) events in a blob container with the data that it needs to be processed as name of the subcontainer, like mycontainer\2016\12\21\myevent1.json (for an event received today and a delay of one month) and have a webjob or whatever run once a day to see it needs to process any blobs of the current date. If so, you could process them and remove/archive the blobs.

Comment: My initial thought was that a polling solution wouldn't be so elegant and that it might also have scaling problems. I would prefer a solution where I can put the delay-logic in some sort of infrastructure that notifies me when an event is due. Having that said, I think that your idea would work and that might be what we will go for if we can't find anything better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned - EventHubs supports only 7 days window of data to be retained.

Event Hubs are typically used as **real-time** telemetry data pipe-lines where data seek performance is critical. For 99.9% usecases/scenarios our users typically require last couple of hours, if not seconds.

However, after the real-time processing is over, and If you still need to re-analyze the data after a while, for ex: run a Hadoop job on last months data - our seek pattern & store are not optimized for it. We recommend to forward the messages to other data archival stores which are specialized for big-data queries.

As - data archival is an ask that most of our customers naturally look for - we are [releasing a new feature which automatically archives the data in AVRO format into Azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-archive-overview).